# can't upload files bigger than 20MB in WordPress media on IIS sever

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I am using IIS server and already changed in my PHP.ini file. But still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by using the wp-config file

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '20M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '13M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '15M' );
```

For more details you can see my source here https://www.cloudways.com/blog/increase-media-file-maximum-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

```
     you can create php.ini file in wp_admin folder in root wordpress directory 

     open php.ini and override  these values 
          1- upload max size 
          2- post max size 
          3- max execution time
      now php.ini file looks like that 
             upload_max_filesize = 128M
             post_max_size = 128M
             max_execution_time = 180
```